# Best microdata in HTML blog markup

Tags: html, microdata

I've just started using microdata in blog markup for SEO purposes. However, I'm not sure whether I'm using it correctly or in the best way.

I have a page with a blog post and a blog archive (list of other blog links). The markup currently looks like this:

```
<!--BLOG POST-->
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Blog Title</h1>
  <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2014-01-14">
  <span class="blogDate">2014-01-14</span>
  <span itemprop="author">Rich Cooper</span>
  <article itemprop="articleBody">Content in here</article>
</div>

<!--BLOG ARCHIVE-->
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
  <li itemprop="blogPosts" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    <a href="blog-link" itemprop="url">Blog 1 title</a> 
    <time itemprop="date" datetime="2014-02-01">2014-02-01</time>
  </li>
  <li itemprop="blogPosts" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    <a href="blog-link" itemprop="url">Blog 2 title</a> 
    <time itemprop="date" datetime="2014-01-15">2014-01-15</time>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help here with the correct microdata markup and best practices would be really useful.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you add a `meta` element for the `datePublished` property when you show the date in a `span` anyway? So instead of

```html
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2014-01-14">
<span class="blogDate">2014-01-14</span>
```

you could use:

```html
<span class="blogDate" itemprop="datePublished">2014-01-14</span>
```

And why not use the [`time` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) here?

```html
<time class="blogDate" itemprop="datePublished">2014-01-14</time>
```

---

The `article` element should be used for the whole blog post, not just the text body. So replace `div` with `article` and vice-versa:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Blog Title</h1>
  <time class="blogDate" itemprop="datePublished">2014-01-14</time>
  <span itemprop="author">Rich Cooper</span>
  <div itemprop="articleBody">Content in here</div>
</article>
```

This allows you to use a `header`/`footer` for the "metadata" (like publication date and author).

---

Schema.org doesn’t define a property named `date`. You should probably use `datePublished` instead.

---

You could (not must) add the main blog post as child of the `Blog` item, too:

(and I’d use a sectioning element for the "archive posts",)

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">

  <article itemprop="blogPosts" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    <!-- … -->
  </article>

  <section>
    <h1>Post archive</h1> <!-- or omit this heading -->
      <ul>
        <li itemprop="blogPosts" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"><!-- … --></li>
        <li itemprop="blogPosts" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"><!-- … --></li>
      </ul>
  </section>

</div>
```